# Microsoft Partner Center Price Sheet API: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ''

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-partner-center

I get this error :

AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '' named ''. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. Trace ID: 9cc0a97c-b602-4cb1-8325-545833b47b00 Correlation ID: 00853d8f-9f51-4708-b44b-3f0392503b1f Timestamp: 2024-02-14 17:41:18Z

anytime i generate a refresh_token and try to use this refresh token to get an access token that i can then pass to the price sheet api to get price sheet for a region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that: To call Microsoft Partner API, you must grant Microsoft Partner API permissions to the Microsoft Entra application.

**Grant Admin consent to the below API permission:**

[image]

**I used below endpoint to authorize users:**

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https://api.partner.microsoft-int.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

[image]

Access token generated successfully:

[image]

**If still the issue persists,** *Go to Microsoft Entra ID -> Enterprise applications -> User settings -> Consent and permissions*

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this works!! I had to pay some one show me this trick with the api permission. However Wish Microsoft could update their documentation. It took me a whooping 3 months to get price sheets from the API.